# Facebook PHP SDK: (#200) Subject does not have permission to create live video on this group

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I'm implementating the live video posting to a facebook group.
I have the "publish_to_groups" permission provided by facebook but still i'm getting the error "(#200) Subject does not have permission to create live video on this group"

Step which i have flollowed:

1. Authorised the user via login
2. Get an accesstoken for posting the video to groups
3. Get a list of groups of that user
4. User has to choose a group to post
5. Make a post query to post the video to that group

```php
// Get list of Groups
$response = $fb->get("/$user_id/groups", $accessToken);

// Post the video to any one group
$response = $fb->post("/$groupID/live_videos", array (
    'status' => 'LIVE_NOW',
    'title' => $config['videoTitle'],
    'description' => $config['videoDesc'],
    'privacy' => array("value" => "EVERYONE")
), $accessToken);
```

Expected Result: Video should be posted to that group.

Actual Result: Getting the Error:- (#200) Subject does not have permission to create live video on this group

Comment: Since posting to a group feed requires that the app was installed in the group by a group admin, I would assume that this is probably the same for live videos.

Comment: You're right, uploading videos to a group requires the app to be installed in that group by the group admin. But FYI for live videos there is no need to install the app.